# How can I define vector of points in Scala?

Tags: scala, vector

I want to translate [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622855/process-on-curve-path-skeleton-binary-image) to Scala and I have problem with defining a vector of points in Scala:

```
 vector<Point> vect1;
```

can anyone help me on that? 
I tried :

```
val vect1=new Vector[Point] ()
```

but is gives me "not enough arguments for constructor Vector" error!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `new` keyword for creating a Vector.  Instead, you'll use methods `apply` or `empty` on the companion object.

The syntax is:

```
val vect1 = Vector[Point]()        // same as Vector.apply[Point]()
```

or

```
val vect1 = Vector.empty[Point]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried both of them but it gives me : " type mismatch" error don't get it what is the problem!

Comment: The code I posted works just fine.  There must be something to your question that you aren't stating.

Comment: Thank you I just realized a small problem in my code, I fixed it and now I don't get any errors. May I bother you more during translation of that code?